# Character creation for more experienced mages

Tags: character-creation, world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

What is the rule to create more experienced mages in Mage: The Ascension? How many points do you have to create an elder mage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### In Mage, the "elder" equivalent is "archmage."

And you can find the rules for making those in *[Masters of the Art](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/205/Masters-of-the-Art)*. Character creation rules in that book start on page 81 — like elder vampires, they get a lot of additional dots to start with and aren’t limited to five dots in their traits, including Spheres.

- Attributes: 8/6/4
- Abilities: 19/13/7
- Spheres: 12, with at least one at six (••••••)
- Willpower: Starts at 6
- Arete: Starts at 6
- Backgrounds: 10
- Freebie Points: 30
- Merits and Flaws: Up to 7, as normal

Answer (score 2):

There are no rules in the rulebook for creating more experienced characters, nor is "elder mage" a defined status for mages (though it is used by vampires).

From my experience, the easiest way to create experienced characters is to create a starting character to make sure you have a solid base, and then reward experience to spend after the initial creation.

To create an "elder mage" of sorts, the player should take the Status background to confer that importance onto them.  Points in Chantry, Node, or Cult could also establish the character as an elder of sorts.

If you mean elder as in just an old mage, no special background would be required.  Some life spheres to extend their longevity may be all that they need.

Comment: This is explicitly how *Vampire: the Masquerade* approaches creating elder-level vampires as PCs: you choose how old you want them to be upfront and then assign extra experience points (drawn from a table) based on that. I'm less familiar with *M:tA*, but if the systems are as similar as they were in Revised the *V:tM* approach might be directly applicable for *M:tA*.